# Performing a method() upon exit of a loop java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have made a for loop with a nested if block. On exit of the loop I want the object to perform an action by calling a method. At the moment I am struggling to find how to do this. Could anyone make any suggestions?. Below is the code I have made.

```
public void goLoop()
   {
    for (int i = 1; i <= getAmountOfLoops(); i++ )
    {
      if (getPosition() => 25)
      {
         this.setPosition(4);
      }
      else
      {
        this.keepLooping();
        this.setTotalAmountOfLoops(getTotalAmountOfLoops() + 2);    
      }
      jump();   // Do I put the action to perform on exit of loop here?   
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just put it after the loop?

Comment: there is no nested if present in your code and there is nothing like if loop. its `if-else` or `nested if-else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it after the loop:

```
for (... ) {

}
action();
```

BTW change `getPosition() => 25` to `getPosition() >= 25`.

Note: It's always better to be aware of the logic of your program before you start coding, however if you start coding and suddenly encounter a trivial situation like this, **just give it a try!** and check if it produces the desired result or not.